# Unable to make CSS3 animation play

Tags: css, css-animations

I've got the code below that I want to make some `div` bounce. At the moment they don't seem to move at all, where am I going wrong?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nu78enm3/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounceup {
    0% { -webkit-transform:translateY(0); }
    40% { -webkit-transform:translateY(30px); } 
    60% { -webkit-transform:translateY(15px); }
}

@keyframes bounceup {
    0% { transform:translateY(0); }
    40% { transform:translateY(30px); } 
    60% { transform:translateY(15px); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceleft {
    0% { -webkit-transform:translateX(0); }
    40% { -webkit-transform:translateX(-30px); }    
    60% { -webkit-transform:translateX(-15px); }
}

@keyframes bounceleft {
    0% { transform:translateX(0); }
    40% { transform:translateX(-30px); }    
    60% { transform:translateX(-15px); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceright {
    0% { -webkit-transform:translateX(0); }
    40% { -webkit-transform:translateX(30px); } 
    60% { -webkit-transform:translateX(15px); }
}

@keyframes bounceright {
    0% { transform:translateX(0); }
    40% { transform:translateX(30px); } 
    60% { transform:translateX(15px); }
}

.bounceup {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceup 2s infinite;
  animation-name: bounceup 2s infinite;
}

.bounceleft {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceleft 2s infinite;   
  animation-name: bounceleft 2s infinite;
}

.bounceright {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceright 2s infinite;  
  animation-name: bounceright 2s infinite;
}
```

Comment: Demo please. At a glance, can't see anything wrong there. (*Edit:* Sorry, you are using `animation-name` property which should be used only to set the animation's name instead of using the shorthand `animation` property and that's the error.)

Comment: @Harry Just added a fiddle. So replace animation-name with animation?

Comment: I updated my answer for your shorthand technique, it works perfectly see my fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be with how you set your animations in your classes. You are using `animation-name`, but you are declaring more than just the name; you are adding values for `animation-iteration-count` and `animation-duration` as well.

Try instead:

```
.bounceup {
  -webkit-animation: bounceup 2s infinite;
  animation: bounceup 2s infinite;
}

.bounceleft {
  -webkit-animation: bounceleft 2s infinite;   
  animation: bounceleft 2s infinite;
}

.bounceright {
  -webkit-animation: bounceright 2s infinite;  
  animation: bounceright 2s infinite;
}
```

#### Edit:

Seems like @Harry modified his comment and pointed precisely the above. Basically you were trying to use the shorthand version of `animation` but for the `animation-name` property.

An alternative solution would be (the non-shorthand version):

```
.bounceup {
  animation-name: bounceup;
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceup;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a working copy for you:

```
  -webkit-animation: bounceup 5s infinite;
  animation: bounceup 5s infinite;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nu78enm3/2/

and a link to the shorthand technique:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp